# set Second validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set a Second validation message for my password input, but it doesn't work, can you help me out?

This is my tag:

```
<input id="password" style="text-align:center;" type="text" name="password"
       tabindex="3" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9].{5,}" title="" required
       oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter a password')"
       oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"
       onkeyup="deleteBadConfirm(); valid_pass();" />
```

and this is mu js function for the second validation message:

```
function valid_pass() {
  if(document.getElementById("password").value != "") {
    document.getElementById("password")
            .setCustomValidity('At least, enter 6 characters; Don't use any symbols');
  };
};

function deleteBadConfirm() {
  $("#confirmpassword").prop("value", "");
};
```

EDIT: This is how it's supposed to go down:
if the user press submit before entering a password, the message says "please enter a password". Then, if the user enters a password, but it's not valid, this time the message should say"At least, enter 6 ...". Now, it shows the first message, but then, if I enter less than 6 characters, it still brings up the old message, and if I enter 6 invalid characters, it won't show any message!!

Comment: 'At least, enter 6 characters; Don't use any symbols'
is this message dont show up???

Comment: can you explain in step by step format

Comment: I just edited the question and explained the way that I need it to work

Answer (score 1):

You have a error in below line
Change this

```
 document.getElementById("password")
            .setCustomValidity('At least, enter 6 characters; Don't use any symbols');
```

To

```
document.getElementById("password")
            .setCustomValidity('At least, enter 6 characters; Don\'t use any symbols');
```

by adding a escape character - backslash ()

Answer (score 1):

Clear the `oninvalid` event or it will always override your `setCustomValidity`. Added the `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class to check if value is valid or not.

```js
function valid_pass() {
  if (document.getElementById("password").value != "") {
    if ($('#password').is(":invalid")) {
      document.getElementById("password")
        .setCustomValidity('At least, enter 6 characters; Don\'t use any symbols');
    };
  } else {
    document.getElementById("password")
      .setCustomValidity('Please enter a password');
  };
};

function deleteBadConfirm() {
  $("#confirmpassword").prop("value", "");
};

//Added this to show setCustomValidity message/tooltip without submit event
function runReportValidity() {
  document.getElementById("password").reportValidity();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="password" style="text-align:center;" type="text" name="password" tabindex="3" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9].{5,}" title="" required oninvalid="valid_pass()" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" onkeyup="deleteBadConfirm(); valid_pass();" />

<!-- Added this to show setCustomValidity message/tooltip without submit event -->
<input type="button" onClick="runReportValidity()" value="Report Validity">
```

Comment: That kinda worked, but I still have a problem: I want the message to show up, only if the given password is invalid; I even had the following if statement in my original code:
`if (document.getElementById("password").invalid) { document.getElementById("password").setCustomValidity('At least, enter 6 ...'); } else {document.getElementById("password").setCustomValidity(''); };`

Comment: @TheMonster Updated my answer now I've seen you edit.